# Создать динамические URL в HTML на основе JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Провожу эксперимент с использованием AMT `Amazon Mechanical Turk`, требуется перенаправлять пользователей с AMT по ссылке на сервер, где они, собственно, принимают участие в эксперименте.

**В чем суть проблемы?**
Чтобы попасть на сервер, пользователям требуется ввести логин и пароль. У каждого пользователя на AMT имеется *ID* код, по которому я могу их распознавать - этот *ID* выполняет функцию логина. Пароли я генерирую заранее (токены), выглядят они примерно так: `4801151f-7489-49cc-a9ce-9c027fe43fcd`. Страница задания написана в `html`,
**цель**: написать код, который бы создавал динамические ссылки для каждого пользователя индивидуально.

Пример такой ссылки (шаблон):
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name=AMAZON_ID_NUMBER_IS_HERE&token=TOKEN_IS_HERE`.
То есть ссылка сама выглядит как ниже (с изменяющимся токеном и id)
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name=AD11235543&token=36473gv-dbdb543-rhr35-edef`

Попытался поработать над кодом, но я что-то делаю не так.

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=createDynamicURL();" > click the link </a>

<script>
  function createDynamicURL()
  {var URL;

  var name
  var token

  URL+="http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name=";
  URL+=name;
  URL+="&amp;token=";
  URL+=token;

  return URL;
  }
```

Подскажите, как создавать такие динамические ссылки с использованием javaScript и html?

Поскольку я новичок в этом деле, то я бы тоже хотел знать, каким методом экспортировать токены в ссылку? Предположим, они хранятся в отдельном файле: как их вставлять в динамическую ссылку?

Comment: А при чем тут java?

Comment: @Виктор один из вариантов, которые можно вставить в `<script>` включал в себя java код с функцией, что-то наподобие следующего:

    `function RedirectURL()
    {
    window.location= createDynamicURL();
    }`, поэтому я и подумал, что это можно в java сделать...подскажите, есть другие варианты?

Comment: очень непонятный вопрос. 
Вам нужно передать utm метки с одного сайта на другой? тогда getUrlParameter в помощь. Если нет - сформулируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос по другому

Comment: Да, не слишком конкретно выразился. Обнаружил проблему.
  
В общем, мне надо изменить url параметры в href ссылке. Эти параметры должны браться из определенного списка. То есть если брать ссылку выше, то мне требуется изменить параметры `name` и `token` каждый раз, когда пользователь проходит по ссылке...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос был не очень ясно мною поставлен, но, вроде бы, разобрался.
Сам Javascript должен выглядеть следующим образом, чтобы генерировать динамические ссылки:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function testing () {
var name="me"
var token="70a55e16-6c22-4789-b0de"

something="http://127.0.0.1:5000/?name=";
something+=name
something+="&token=";
something+=token

window.open(something)
}
</script>
```

Контент для html файла:

```
<a href = "#" onclick="testing()">Click to enter</a>
```

Все оказалось проще, чем я думал. Но есть другая проблема: на место токена требуется вставлять всякий раз новый токен. Токены хранятся в отдельном `txt` файле, который `javascript` должен считывать в `html`...

Comment: у меня есть для вас детальное решение, но оно не помещается в коммент, по-этому напишу в качестве ответа

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

(function () {
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'file.txt', false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        alert(response);
    }
})();
```

этот код посылает ajax запрос и вытаскивает из file.txt всю инфу, потом записывает в переменную `response` и выводит ее alert`ом

Дальше уже ваше дело, как парсить текст

Comment: txt файл должен хранится в том же репозитории, как я понимаю?  

я вывожу данные не на своем сервере, а на AMT, который, видимо, не дает мне возможности выводить информацию из локальных файлов, хранящихся на компьютере, ибо всякий раз, когда я пытаюсь это сделать, меня просто перебрасывает на начало html страницы...

Comment: "txt файл должен хранится в том же репозитории, как я понимаю?" - да, на js по другому никак. Тут видимо без php не обойтись. Хотя я до сих пор смутно понимаю вашу задачу